# product update in sql server 2012 from jframe

Tags: netbeans, sql-server-2012, sql-update

i am able to update a record only one time the second time i try to update that particular record nothing happens..here is my code. i am using sql server 2012 and netbeans 8

```
 try { 
       String url="jdbc:sqlserver://LENOVO-PC\\SQL2012:1433;databaseName=qseal";
       String user="sa";
       String pass="123";  
       Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
       /*   if (con!= null) {
       System.out.println("Connected");
       }*/
       String sql="update inventorytable set product_name=?,quantity=?,price=? where product_code=?";
       PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);

       pst.setString(1, ProductNameTextField.getText());
       pst.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(QuantityTextField.getText()));
       pst.setFloat(3, Float.parseFloat(PriceTextField.getText())); 
       pst.setString(4, ProductCodeTextField.getText());

       pst.executeUpdate();

       ProductCodeTextField.setText("");
       ProductNameTextField.setText("");
       QuantityTextField.setText("");
       PriceTextField.setText("");

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"product updated");
       }                                    
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace(System.out);

      }
```

Comment: I really, really hope for you that your sa password is not 123, even for a local development server.

Comment: its a college project.. i dont really care about the password.. can u help me in solving the main issue here ?

Comment: Sorry, but no. Your update statement seems find and I haven't touched java for about 15-16 years, so...